# OOP interface when using indices for links

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures, idioms

TL;DR: I have a linked data structure, and I decide to use not pointers but indices into a container to express these links. Can I model the individual elements as stand-alone objects for the sake of more readable code without incurring the cost for keeping multiple references to the array?

---

Suppose I have a linked data structure. For the sake of simplicity, let's use a doubly linked list as an example, with an operation to remove a node. Classical way to model this would be using pointers:

```
struct Node {
  Node *prev, *next;
  void remove() { next->prev = prev; prev->next = next; }
};
```

But pointers have a number of drawbacks. They may waste space since pointer size usually can't be chosen to match the use case. They make for a poor wire format. If I keep the nodes in a vector, resizing that may invalidate pointers. Copying the data structures becomes harder. So I could go for indices into some array instead:

```
struct Node {
  int prev, next;
};
struct LinkedList {
  std::vector<Node> nodes;
  void remove(int i) {
    Node& n = nodes[i];
    nodes[n.next].prev = n.prev;
    nodes[n.prev].next = n.next;
  }
};
```

But now the operation that was previously a method of the individual node has become a method of the container class. That semantic shift makes some code harder to read. To avoid that problem, I could go for a representation based on the pair of container and node index.

```
struct Node { int prev, next; };
struct LinkedList;
struct NodeRef {
  int i;
  LinkedList& l;  // This reference here is what's worrying me
  NodeRef(int index, LinkedList& list) : i(index), l(list) {}
  NodeRef prev() const;
  NodeRef next() const;
  void remove();
};
struct LinkedList {
  std::vector<Node> nodes;
  NodeRef root() { return NodeRef(0, *this); }
};
NodeRef NodeRef::prev() const { return NodeRef(l.nodes[i].prev, l); }
NodeRef NodeRef::next() const { return NodeRef(l.nodes[i].next, l); }
void NodeRef::remove() {
  Node& n = l.nodes[i];
  l.nodes[n.next].prev = n.prev;
  l.nodes[n.prev].next = n.next;
}
```

So now I can use NodeRef to express my algorithm in a nicely object-oriented manner, with the node as an entity I can iteract with, while at the same time using indices instead of pointers behind the scenes.

But when I have some complicated algorithm operating with multiple nodes at the same time, then I'd have multiple NodeRef objects all referencing the same underlying LinkedList object. That feels kind of wasteful, both in terms of memory consumption and work to copy them. I would *guess* that a compiler *might* be able to detect some of that redundancy and get rid of it. But is there anything I could do to help it, to ensure that this will get optimized to only use a single reference even though semantically I have multiple?

Comment: have you considered using an `operator[]` overload to abstract away the interactions, and smart pointers for the connections? Smart pointers could also deal with the multiple NodeRef objects problem.

Comment: @Tzalumen: Smart pointers are inherently tricky when there is no clear ownership, which is the case with most linked data structures that are not trees. Main benefit of smart pointers is decent RAII-based cleanup, but cleanup is not even one of the problems with pointers I listed, so all the issues I listed would still apply to smart pointers. Not sure how you'd use the `operator[]` here. Defining it on `LinkedList` to construct a `NodeRef` could make the abstracting code simpler to read but would not affect the question at hand since the redundant reference would still be there.

Comment: Have you looked at `std::weak_ptr` and `std::shared_from_this`? `weak_ptr` is for final pointers in a cycle, and `shared_from_this` gives you an easy way to enforce shared ownership by multiple `NodeRef` referencing the same `LinkedList`.

Comment: For a separate question, is there a reason you're not just using a `std::list` instead of rolling your own?

Answer (score 1):

You could require that `LinkedList` be supplied when you want to act on a `NodeRef`, and then have an accessing object or a lambda which stores your single reference and wraps calls to the `NodeRef`.

For example to remove nodes from the list you could use:

```
struct NodeRef
{
  int i;
  // LinkedList& l;  // Remove this
  NodeRef(int index) : i(index) {}
  NodeRef prev(LinkedList& l) const;
  NodeRef next(LinkedList& l) const;
  void remove(LinkedList& l);
};
// Require that a list is supplied instead of storing a ref
void NodeRef::remove(LinkedList& l)
{
  Node& n = l.nodes[i];
  l.nodes[n.next].prev = n.prev;
  l.nodes[n.prev].next = n.next;
}

// create a lambda with a captured list that wraps the call
LinkedList linkedList;
//...
auto remover = [&linkedList](NodeRef node)
{
  node.remove(linkedList);
};
//...
NodeRef nodeRef(0);
remover(nodeRef);
```

Not sure if this is what you want, but it avoids multiple references to the list and could allow reuse of the `NodeRef` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be using templates to store a static pointer to the list, shared between all derived classes. Using different int's to differentiate your lists and `NodeRef`'s. You're forced to manage those ints at compile time so again, probably not ideal, but it does solve the multiple reference issue.

```
#include <vector>

template <int X>
struct LinkedList;

template <int X>
struct NodeRef
{
  static LinkedList<X>* l;
  int i;
  NodeRef(int index) : i(index) {}
  NodeRef prev() const;
  NodeRef next() const;
  void remove();
};

struct Node { int prev, next; };

template <int X>
struct LinkedList 
{
  LinkedList() 
  {
      NodeRef<X>::l = this;
  }
  std::vector<Node> nodes;
  NodeRef<X> root() { return NodeRef<X>(0); }
};


// Use the static pointer
template<int X>
void NodeRef<X>::remove()
{
  auto& l = *NodeRef<X>::l;
  Node& n = l.nodes[i];
  l.nodes[n.next].prev = n.prev;
  l.nodes[n.prev].next = n.next;
}



int main()
{
    LinkedList<0> linkedList;

    // All node refs templated by 0 share the list pointer
    auto nodeRef = linkedList.root();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make all `LinkedList`s share one pool of `Node`s:

```
struct LinkedList {
  static std::vector<Node> nodes; // <-- static
  void remove(int i) {
    Node& n = nodes[i];
    nodes[n.next].prev = n.prev;
    nodes[n.prev].next = n.next;
  }
};
```

This way, for a `NodeRef` the index alone is fully sufficient to identify the referenced `Node`.

Note however, that depending on how frequently `LinkedList`s and `Node`s are created, modified, and destroyed, you may get performance issues here due to cache misses because `Node`s that are neighbors in a list may not be neighbors at all in memory.
This issue may exist with your current approach already. In that case a global `Node` pool will make it even worse.

Also, if you have a multi-threaded application, you will have to perform the usual locking mechanisms which will slow down your app even more.